# Unable to mount Windows 8.1 partition in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows-8, ntfs

I have to install Windows 8.1 on a new laptop and it works O.K. I installed Ubuntu on the same lap and also works O.K.

There is only one problem: Ubuntu can't mount the windows partitions and an error appears for each one of them. Every time I turn on the lap, I have to press "S" to skip mounting those partitions. I tried with `config-ntfs` to mount / unmount those partition, but it didn't work.

Config-ntfs has disabled undo option.
I have experience with windows, but it's the second time I install Ubuntu.
Windows 7 and Ubuntu work perfect on this laptop !!
How can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot into Windows, shut down or restart the laptop/PC normally. Don't force shut down (by pressing power button for 5 seconds). After a clean shut down/restart, the access to NTFS partitions in Ubuntu should be fine. No need to press <kbd>s</kbd> for skip mounting just like normal boot.

One more thing: don't hibernate the laptop/pc when you boot into windows. That is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @swift: This is a perfectly valid answer. It solves the problem and describes the necessary steps in enough details.

Comment: @David Foerster, since I'm edited it ... logically IS NOT. Let's think. It is not solve the problem. Just suggest for reboot without hibernate. Alike a bot. And I am in doubt why I decided to edit it. Really so called 'unconstructive'.

Comment: though maybe you're right

Comment: Sure, there may be more elegant solutions depending on what you consider “elegant”, but shutting down Windows without hibernation is exactly what I'd tell my grandmother, if she called with that problem and I don't have remote shell access to her machine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was very simple! Ubuntu has a program, named Disks, that can mount / dismount any partition type.
Ubuntu was RIGHT ! Windows 8.1 is an unsafe partition, it acts as an ADWARE. If you try to install a program and Microsoft AppStore has some version of it, you will receive an advice and the AppStore will be automatic installed in your taskbar. For example, Microsoft has a version of CodeBlocks, so...if you try to install the "Code::Blocks, The open source, cross-platform IDE" you will have some problems. If you still insist to install it, it doesn't work because the searchpath was changed by "smarterrortxt" program received in background, in a xml file. The problem can be solved, but if you try to install Spybot, a warning will be displayed (incompatibility problem; redirection to microsoft help) and it isn't easy to solve it. The new Spybot detects some file of windows 8.1 as adware, and is RIGHT !